# Mobile menu toggle onclick

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have this html to display a menu and also the mobile version of the menu, however the mobile version is not working, do you know what is necessary to only show the menu on button click and also close the menu on button click? As it is on the mobile version the menu already appears open with the button to close but the button dont hide the menu.

HTML:

```
                <span class="text-xl text-3xl font-bold">logo</span>
              </div>
              <div class="-mr-2 flex items-center md:hidden">
                <button type="button" class="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500" aria-expanded="false">
                  <span class="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
             
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="hidden md:block md:ml-10 mt-2 md:pr-4 md:space-x-8">

            <a href="#" class="font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">Link 1</a>

            <a href="#" class="font-medium text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-900">Link 2</a>

          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="absolute top-0 inset-x-0 p-2 transition transform origin-top-right md:hidden">
        <div class="rounded-lg shadow-md bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 overflow-hidden">
          <div class="px-5 pt-4 flex items-center justify-between">
            <div class="flex">
             
             
              <span class="text-xl text-3xl font-bold text-gray-600">logo</span>
            </div>
            <div class="-mr-2">
              <button type="button" class="bg-white rounded-md p-2 inline-flex items-center justify-center text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500">
                <span class="sr-only">Close main menu</span>
                <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                </svg>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1">

            <a href="#" class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50">Link 1</a>

            <a href="#" class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50">Link 2</a>

            <a href="#" class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-50">Link 3</a>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <main class="mt-10 mx-auto max-w-7xl px-4 sm:mt-12 sm:px-6 md:mt-16 lg:mt-20 lg:px-8 xl:mt-28">
        <div class="sm:text-center lg:text-left">
          <h1 class="text-4xl tracking-tight font-extrabold text-gray-600 sm:text-5xl md:text-6xl">
            <span class="block xl:inline">Test</span>
          </h1>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="lg:absolute lg:inset-y-0 lg:right-0 lg:w-1/2">
    <img class="h-56 w-full object-cover sm:h-72 md:h-96 lg:w-full lg:h-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use some javascript to achieve this.

On your mobile navigation you'll want to do this:

```
<button id="toggle-mobile-nav-btn">Toggle nav</button>
<nav id="mobile-nav" class="hidden">
   <!-- Nav content -->
</nav>
```

Then, in js, you'll want to create an event listener that will run when a user makes a `click` event on the toggle button.
(I wrapped that in a DOMContentLoaded eventlistener, to make sure the entire DOM is loaded before executing the script).

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const nav = document.querySelector('#mobile-nav');
  const toggleBtn = document.querySelector('#toggle-mobile-nav-btn');

  toggleBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // On click, we toggle the hidden class on the navigation
    nav.classList.toggle('hidden');
    console.log('Nav toggled!);
  });
})
```

This should toggle your navigation.
You can create a custom css class (instead of Tailwind's `hidden` class) to add transitions to your navigation. That way, you can add nice effects like sliding etc.